# Detect iTerm2 terminal over a SSH session?

Tags: shell, ssh, iterm2

I want to send some proprietary escapes to iTerm2 (to override background colour in current colour profile) if my session is running over SSH.

In order to not screw up the terminal or print garbage when other terminals are used, I want to detect if the terminal is actually iTerm2.
According to information found on the net [1] one can check `ITERM_SESSION_ID` environment var. However, this variable is set for a local session, but not set when SSHing to another machine.

The idea is to put something like the following in my .zshrc (I use the same .zshrc on all machines):

```
if [ -n "$SSH_CLIENT" ] || [ -n "$SSH_TTY" ]; then

    # we are running over SSH...

    if [ -n "$ITERM_SESSION_ID" ]; then
        # change terminal bg color:
        # (can do more advanced stuff to better identify the remote machine)

        echo -e '\e]1337;SetColors=bg=525\a'
    fi
fi
```

However, given that variable `ITERM_SESSION_ID` is reset when SSHing, it would not work.

I would need to set `SendEnv`/`AcceptEnv` on ssh client/server respectively, however it seems like a bad idea.

Any other way to achieve a similar result (use proprietary escapes only if supported?)?

Or I should simply not care if those are not supported?

1: https://groups.google.com/g/iterm2-discuss/c/MpOWDIn6QTs?pli=1

Answer (score 2):

VT100-like terminals can be set to send an identification string when it receives an ENQ character (Ctrl-E, ASCII 005). This includes almost any modern terminal you might use--PuTTY, XTerm, iTerm2, and so on. This feature is sometimes called "answerback".

In the case of iTerm2, the answerback feature is briefly documented [here](https://iterm2.com/documentation-preferences-profiles-terminal.html). You can configure the answerback string on the "Terminal" tab:

[image]

The default answerback for iTerm2 is an empty string, so you'd have to change it in your profile. This has the advantage that you can put anything you like in the profile and possibly use different answerbacks for different purposes.

[This post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/312978/41659) on https://unix.stackexchange.com/ discusses the feature in more detail, including what you might expect to get from other terminals and how to read the string reliably in a script. Briefly, one of the suggestions is to run this command:

```
stty raw min 0 time 5; echo -ne '\005' && read -s; stty cooked; echo -n "${REPLY}"
```

will send the ENQ character and wait a short time for the client to respond. The client may not send anything, or its response may not be terminated with a newline.

Answer (score 0):

From [this discussion on the iterm2-discuss  mailing list](https://groups.google.com/g/iterm2-discuss/c/MpOWDIn6QTs?pli=1):

> I think I figured out how to tell if your terminal is iTerm2. It needs
> testing before wide deployment on different platforms.
>
> The problem has always been that environment variables don't get
> passed through and almost all terminals don't support an escape
> sequence to report version number. Commit cc8436b adds support for a
> new escape sequence that reports the terminal name and version number
> that should be ignored by all other terminals. The trick is you can't
> just ask for the version and then read it back because that'll hang
> indefinitely if the terminal doesn't support the new sequence.
> Instead, you send the custom sequence and then a standard "device
> status report" which every terminal supports. Then you read back one
> response, and if it's a DSR response you quit, knowing it's not
> iTerm2. Otherwise, read both responses.
>
> Commit 95c439f44a77e2419c73e2a44e7f0b423ed37368 adds a shell script
> that tests if the current terminal is iTerm2 and optionally checks if
> its version number is greater than or equal to one you specify.
>
> It will only work on versions of iTerm2 that support this new escape
> sequence, starting with tomorrow's nightly build (2.9.20160304).
>
> tl;dr: You can tell if a terminal is iTerm2 by using this script:
> https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gnachman/iTerm2/master/tests/isiterm2.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Make sure stdin and stdout are a tty.
if [ ! -t 0 ] ; then
  exit 1
fi
if [ ! -t 1 ] ; then
  exit 1
fi

# Read some bytes from stdin. Pass the number of bytes to read as the first argument.
function read_bytes()
{
  numbytes=$1
  dd bs=1 count=$numbytes 2>/dev/null
}

function read_dsr() {
  # Reading response to DSR.
  dsr=""
  spam=$(read_bytes 2)
  byte=$(read_bytes 1)
  while [ "${byte}" != "n" ]; do
    dsr=${dsr}${byte}
    byte=$(read_bytes 1)
  done
  echo ${dsr}
}

# Extract the terminal name from DSR 1337
function terminal {
  echo -n "$1" | sed -e 's/ .*//'
}

# Extract the version number from DSR 1337
function version {
  echo -n "$1" | sed -e 's/.* //'
}

trap clean_up EXIT
_STTY=$(stty -g)      ## Save current terminal setup

function clean_up() {
  stty "$_STTY"            ## Restore terminal settings
}

# Prepare to silently read any (>=0) characters with no timeout.
stty -echo -icanon raw min 0 time 0

# Consume all pending input.
while read none; do :; done

# Reset the TTY, so it behaves as expected for the rest of the it2check script.
clean_up 

# Enter raw mode and turn off echo so the terminal and I can chat quietly.
stty -echo -icanon raw

# Support for the extension first appears in this version of iTerm2:
MIN_VERSION=2.9.20160304
if [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
  MIN_VERSION=$1
fi

# Send iTerm2-proprietary code. Other terminals ought to ignore it (but are
# free to use it respectfully).  The response won't start with a 0 so we can
# distinguish it from the response to DSR 5. It should contain the terminal's
# name followed by a space followed by its version number and be terminated
# with an n.
echo -en '\e[1337n'

# Report device status. Responds with esc [ 0 n. All terminals support this. We
# do this because if the terminal will not respond to iTerm2's custom escape
# sequence, we can still read from stdin without blocking indefinitely.
echo -en '\e[5n'

version_string=$(read_dsr)
if [ -n "${version_string}" -a "${version_string}" != "0" -a "${version_string}" != "3" ]; then
  # Already read DSR 1337. Read DSR 5 and throw it away.
  dsr=$(read_dsr)
else
  # Terminal didn't respond to the DSR 1337. The response we read is from DSR 5.
  version_string=""
fi

# Extract the terminal name and version number from the response.
version=$(version "${version_string}")
term=$(terminal "${version_string}")

# Check if they match what we're looking for. This becomes the return code of the script.
test "$term" = ITERM2 -a \( "$version" \> "$MIN_VERSION" -o "$version" = "$MIN_VERSION" \)
```

Script available here: https://iterm2.com/utilities/it2check

Note: I replaced raw escape char with `-e '\e'` in the above script.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, in a SSH session, LC_* variables should pass.

Those are a good idea to pass, along with $LANG, as their goal is to set the locales and customize the environment. They aren't intended to create configuration issues or a specific security risk.

To ensure so, on the server, check the AcceptEnv configuration:

```
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
```

This is useful as iTerm2 defines `LC_TERMINAL=iTerm2` in your session in addition to other variables like `ITERM_PROFILE`, `TERM_PROGRAM`, `__CFBundleIdentifier` and `ITERM_SESSION_ID`.

Security risk is mitigated as more dangerous variables like LD_PRELOAD can't pass on your session.

So, on the server, when you connect to SSH, you have access to $LC_TERMINAL environment variable and can so use it for your need:

```
$  env | grep -i iterm
LC_TERMINAL=iTerm2
```